# Create a Mashery API Definition that can be accessed without authentication

Tags: authentication, tibco, tibco-topic, mashery

I manage to create so many API Definition that always using oauth 2 or Api Key, but how to create a definition without any authorization (just link as is) ? like a deeplink or shortened url that no need any authorization.

I see **custom** options but don'e know how to use it.

[image]

Any advise welcome, 
thank you

Regards,
Sigit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mashery, open endpoints are created using a workaround method.

1. Keep the request authentication method as 'API Key'
2. Using a common(or a default) account, create a custom key with value `noapikey` for the package-plan under with the endpoint will be exposed
3. In the endpoint level setting, the is a setting called 'Allow calls having no API Key`. Set that value to true.
4. Now the endpoint will be accessible with out any authentication

The logic is that all the calls without an Api Key is mapped to this default `noapikey`, which means we need to take care of the throttle and call limits for the default key.